# An SQL query with OFFSET/FETCH is returning unexpected results

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by, where-clause

I have an SQL Server 2019 database table named `User` with 1,000 rows as follows:

[image: User Table]

I am having a hard time understanding how this `SELECT` query with `OFFSET`/`FETCH` is returning unexpected results:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [User]
WHERE (([NameGiven] LIKE '%1%') 
       OR ([NameFamily] LIKE '%2%'))
ORDER BY [Id] ASC 
    OFFSET 200 ROWS FETCH NEXT 100 ROWS ONLY;
```

Query results:

[image: Query Results]

The results range from 264 to 452 with a total of 100 rows. Why would the records 201, 211, etc. not show up? Am I wrong in my expectations or is there a mistake in the query criteria?

If I remove the `OFFSET`/`FETCH` options from the `ORDER BY` clause, the results are as expected. That makes me think that the `WHERE` clause is not the problem.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you expect the offset to happen before the filter but in actuality it doesn't happen until after the filter. Think about a simpler example where you want all the people named 'sam' and there are more people named 'sam' than your offset:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.foo(id int, name varchar(32));

INSERT dbo.foo(id, name) VALUES
(1, 'sam'),
(2, 'sam'),
(3, 'bob'),
(4, 'sam'),
(5, 'sam'),
(6, 'sam');
```

If you just say:

```
SELECT id FROM dbo.foo WHERE name = 'sam';
```

You get:

```
1
2
4
5
6
```

If you then add an offset of 3,

```
-- this offsets 3 rows _from the filtered result_,
-- not the full table

SELECT id FROM dbo.foo 
WHERE name = 'sam'
ORDER BY id
OFFSET 3 ROWS FETCH NEXT 2 ROWS ONLY;
```

You get:

```
5
6
```

It takes all the rows *that match the filter*, then skips the first three *of those filtered rows* (1,2,4) - not 1,2,3 like your question implies that you expect.

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=143554d92a70b2c311b2d50086c1baae)

Going back to your case in the question, you are filtering out rows like 77 and 89 because they don't contain a 1 or a 2. So the offset you asked for is 200, but in terms of which rows that means, the offset is actually more like:

```
200 PLUS the number of rows that *don't* match your filter
         until you hit the 200th row that *does*
```

You could try to force the filter to happen after, e.g.:

```
;WITH u AS 
(
  SELECT * 
  FROM [User]
  ORDER BY [Id]
  OFFSET 200 ROWS FETCH NEXT 100 ROWS ONLY
)
SELECT * FROM u
  WHERE (([NameGiven] LIKE '%1%') 
     OR ([NameFamily] LIKE '%2%'))
ORDER BY [Id]; -- yes you still need this one
```

...but then you would almost certainly never get 100 rows in each page because some of those 100 rows would then be removed by the filter. I don't think this is what you're after.

Comment: Thank you. This example makes sense. This means that to achieve the results I want, I can either create a temp table, or return a large data set for the client to filter. Both approaches seem inefficient.

Comment: The objective is to get the first 200 rows that match the filter, NOT to filter out of the first 200 rows. If you were to iterate using a `CURSOR` for example, you would include the first 200 matching rows and break out of the loop. I am new to `db<>fiddle` and will try to set up an example for you.

Comment: You are correct. All this time I was thinking from a pagination perspective and was using `OFFSET` to skip over ALL the rows in the table instead of just the filtered ones. In other words, in my client-minded approach, I was expecting the `ORDER BY` to FIRST segment, and THEN filter.

Comment: @RaheelKhan `OFFSET` is itself inefficient, as it requires reading all previous rows and skipping them. You may want to look at Keyset Pagination, which is generally more efficient

Comment: That article, while interesting, isn't about keyset pagination. It's about forcing the `OFFSET` to happen before the clustered key lookup. Keyset pagination doesn't offset by row-number at all, it jumps straight to the next key after the last one retrieved, and is far more efficient than either option you provided. See https://use-the-index-luke.com/no-offset. It also gains in the fact it doesn't miss rows if earlier ones are deleted.

Comment: Sorry, hard to understand your meaning over the wire, are you being sarcastic, is there something you disagree with? I wasn't trying to be rude, it's a great article. Just I don't think that's quite what Keyset Pagination is, your article seems to refer more to efficiencies in Rowset Pagination.